# VKRoadTile? Weird console error

Tags: iphone, ios, urbanairship.com

```
MESH TOO LARGE!!! VKRoadTile: Too many road points for tile 0.0.1 (512)
```

What is this?

It appears in my console but I can't find any reference to anything it refers to anywhere online!

Comment: It's just an Apple developer's log...

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I set the visiableMapRect of an MKMapView to only a single point rect (no union of multiple point rects).

Comment: I also got the same issue.